# Problem predicting probabilities using tf.nn.softmax instead of tf.argmax

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have searched for this problem and couldn't find any answer that helps me.

I have trained a model and I use tf.argmax(logits, -1) in order to predict the right class (among 98 classes). This works fine and I succeed to predict the result.

Then, I try to see the probabilities that led to this prediction, replacing the tf.argmax command with tf.nn.softmax. When I do this, it predicts an other class that has probability of 0,9 and the class that should predict (which is that when using argmax) has probability of 0.3. Which is wrong, because the result predicted with argmax is correct. Why when i use softmax the probabilities choose an other (not correct) class? Any ideas on what could be the issue there? Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you compare argmax and softmax? Have you trained your model with softmax?

Comment: It seems a bit strange to replace softmax with argmax. tf.nn.softmax generally gives the probability distribution and tf.argmax gives the classes from that distribution.

Comment: i trained the model only with argmax. after the model had trained and used the argmax to make sure it does accurate predictions, i replaced argmax with softmax. should i train the model again with argmax? i dont think i should. What's your opinion?

Comment: The prediction task is from a word to produse phonemes. When I use argmax the result for the word 'gare' is ['g', '"', 'E@', 'r', '+'], which is correct, and for the same word, when i use softmax, the result is ['g', 'E@', 'r', '0' ]